# Why can't I display all glyphs in some fonts?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, glyphs

Why some glyphs are not working from some fonts? They are showing "No Unicode" in the Glyphs panel and I can't access them. I tried also to edit the font and add codes for the glyphs I want, but this method is not working.

Anybody do know how to fix this? I'm using Illustrator CS6 LS6. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please read through our [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how we operate around here and what questions/answers work best! Could you provide more details on the font in question? Does it come from a reputable type foundry? What's the font name? What font format is it?

Comment: This all depends on the actual font file.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a selection of text containing glyphs from the extended set of a Unicode font is converted to a non-Unicode font. The font you're using simply doesn't have that glyph.

Comment: But why then in the glyphs panel the elements are present if I can't access them? I do not understand that )

Comment: My guess would be that the unicode glyphs are being automatically substituted using a system font. Can you share a screen shot of the panel?

Comment: So you can check the links for screenshots:

http://puu.sh/hWes3/228c7d6dd3.jpg
http://puu.sh/hWesJ/d4f1e24bee.jpg

As you can see the character/element on the first screenshot does have a unicode code (U+0026), but the character/element in the second screenshot does not have a unicode code.

Comment: Handsome Script appears to not be a unicode font, so the "No Unicode" message is to be expected. So when you say you can't access them, what exactly do you mean? What is your method and what happens when you try it?